# MySQL select data over time that matches pattern over several rows

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

We currently log data from our plants running remotely for diagnostic purposes on MySQL.

I have been asked to come up with a typical running profile for several variables. For this, I would require to get a pattern where, say, our plant is running in mode 400 for atleast 2 hours (we currently have the datetime column as primary key).

Would it be possible to come up with a query that says "*show rows where plant is running in step 400 for more than 2 hours*"?

Thanks :)

EDIT: Sorry, but one more query to add to that, is it possible to search where a step change occurs, like "search for * where value changes from 0 to 100"?

EDIT2: 
From a comment - an example would be:

```
datetime             plant_status incomer_power
2014-09-04 16:16:57     222     -67.06115
2014-09-04 16:17:27     222     -67.5517
2014-09-04 16:17:57     222     -68.0331
2014-09-04 16:18:27     222     -67.99048
2014-09-04 16:19:27     400     -158.7233
2014-09-04 16:19:57     400     -158.9488
2014-09-04 16:20:27     400     -159.0716
```

This is only a small snapshot of the data. But this data goes on for days. I would like a query, that would bring up the rows when plant_status changed to 400 (only 1 event in case of this example @ 2014-09-04 16:19:27).

Comment: Your question its a bit confusing,could you show some sample data?What do you mean step 400?

Comment: Hi,

One example would be:

    datetime            plant_status incomer_power
    2014-09-04 16:16:57 222 -67.06115
    2014-09-04 16:17:27 222 -67.5517
    2014-09-04 16:17:57 222 -68.0331
    2014-09-04 16:18:27 222 -67.99048
    2014-09-04 16:19:27 400 -158.7233
    2014-09-04 16:19:57 400 -158.9488
    2014-09-04 16:20:27 400 -159.0716

This is only a small snapshot of the data. But this data goes on for days. I would like a query, that would bring up the rows when plant_status changed to 400 (only 1 event in case of this example @ 2014-09-04 16:19:27).

Included as EDIT above as well!

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar on my side, and I use a MySQL Stored Procedure / Cursor.

You loop through each line of the table and record the current datetime entry and plant_status into variables, and then move on to the next line.

At which point you compare the current datetime and plant_status with the last ones.

If it matches a set condition (in your case `new_status` != `last_status`) you add an entry to a temporary table.

And then at the end you simply select * from temporary_table_name to show you all the rows where the status changed.

You could easily convert this to check the datetime as well (changing the old_datetime variable each time the status changes), and comparing that to the current one to find out if there is a two hour difference).
(this probably should be a comment rather than an answer but I don't yet have enough points to comment - sorry)